# Online public database for book readers

Tags: web-apps, database, books

I'm looking for an [imdb](http://www.imdb.com) equivalent for books. The site I want to use should have these specific features:

- book rating
- reviews
- tagging books with tags like *already read*, *own*, *plan to read*...
- support for non-english authors and books
- top lists
- category filters
- info about the author and his/her bibliography
- see what books my friends read or what they read in the past

Also, it should be working, living, non-empty database. Is there any such site?

I've already tried:

- books.google.com
- www.ibookdb.net
- openlibrary.org

None of these fulfills the criteria above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GoodReads matches your needs. Here is the link: [GoodReads](https://www.goodreads.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If you like GoodReads as [suggested by dannemp](/a/43566/185), you might be interested in taking a look at **[BookWyrm](https://bookwyrm.social/)** as well: *BookWyrm* is the libre pendant. No lock-in, but a community of interconnected instances, which is part of the [Fediverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fediverse). Quoting from their own introduction:

> BookWyrm is ad-free, anti-corporate, and federated. You can seamlessly follow and interact with users on other BookWyrm instances, and on services like Mastodon.

Like *Goodreads* it's mainly intended for book cataloging, and offers about the same features. But due to its connections with the Fediverse, is much more versatile. And if you're using Android, there's even a [BookWyrm app](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/nl.privacydragon.bookwyrm) available making not only adding your apps easier (thanks to the integrated barcode scanner):

[image] [image] [image]
<sup>Screenshots of the *BookWyrm* app (click images for larger variants)</sup>